# Nightwatch/Appium configuration for testing browser on iOS emulator

Tags: appium, nightwatch.js, appium-ios

I'm having trouble finding resources related to configuring Nightwatch to use Appium to test a mobile web app.

Is this even possible? Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It involves proper environment set-up and if anything is off you will have errors. I wrote up a full blog on testing iOS browsers with Nightwatch and Appium that is very recent (08/2016)

http://www.shaneofalltrades.com/2016/08/26/Mobile-Web-Testing-Using-Nightwatchjs-part-1/

If you have any issues, feel free to ask here or in the comments. Basically using the default Nightwatch Google test, so you can be sure it is not your tests failing, but configuration if anything. Here is my config example...

```
"ios" : {
  "selenium_start_process": false,
  "selenium_port" : 4723,
  "selenium_host" : "127.0.0.1",
  "silent": true,
  "desiredCapabilities" : {
    "browserName" : "Safari",
    "platformName" : "iOS",
    "platformVersion" : "9.3",
    "deviceName" : "iPhone 6s Plus"
  }
},
```

But please read through and follow the documentation, there are a few unique steps that are important.

Comment: Hi Do you have a sample example using WD (Node.js)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this settings(Nightwatch.js file), it worked for me

```
var path = require('path');

var appPath = path.join(process.cwd(), '<your app path>');// .app file


module.exports = {
    "src_folders": ["./tests/"],
  "globals_path": './lib/globals/Globals.js',

    "selenium": {
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": "node_modules/selenium-server/lib/runner/selenium-server-standalone.jar",
        "log_path": "./results",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 4444,
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./node_modules/.bin/chromedriver"
        }
    },

    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "globals" : {
                "waitForConditionTimeout" : 20000,
            },
            "launch_url": "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub",
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "selenium_port": 4723,
            "silent": true,
            "output": true,
            "screenshots": {
                "enabled": false,
                "path": ""
            },
            "exclude": ['nightwatch-config.js', 'pageObjects']
        },
        "ios-sim": {
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "fullReset": false,
                "app": appPath,
                "platformName": "iOS",
                "platformVersion": "9.0",
                "deviceName": "iPhone 5s"
            }
        }
    }
};
```